# Можно ли при локальном запуске html-страницы назначит в src элемента динамически созданный Blob?

Tags: javascript, html5

Примерный код:

```
var my_blob=new Blob([b_array])
var url=URL.createObjectURL(my_blob);
var e = document.createElement("script");
document.body.appendChild(e)
 ... 
e.src=url
```

Выдает, видимо, защиту песочницы (в начале объекта стоит null - “blob:null/...” а при запуске через сервер, когда все нормально, null не наблюдается)
Unexpected token ILLEGAL